# Looking for a more effective approach to scan and remove text in a large data frame

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tweets

I'm working on a sentiment analysis of tweets, but unfortunately one of the pre-processing steps in my code are not very effective.

The code is a for loop that looks for all words starting with a hashtag and then search for the word in a large vector of about 52,000 words from the Reuters dataset.
If it finds the word in the vector, it removes the hashtag, but keeps the word.

If the for loop does not find the word in the vector, the next code removes both the hashtag and the word.

The tweets are in data_tweet, which is a data frame with a few million rows.

```
library(qdap)
library(tm.corpus.Reuters21578)

data("Reuters21578")

# Makes a list of all words in Reuters and how often they are used
freq_terms <- freq_terms(Reuters21578, Inf)

# Makes a vector with all unique words from Reuters
all_words_vec <-  as.vector(freq_terms$WORD)

# The for loop which is by far the most time consuming part of the code
# Searching for words starting with # and delete them if found in Reuters vector
for (i in 1:length(all_words_vec)) {  
  data_tweet$text <- gsub(paste0("#\\<", all_words_vec[[i]], "\\>"), paste(all_words_vec[[i]], ""), data_tweet$text)  
  (i %% 10000 == 0)  
  cat(i)  
  cat("..")  
}

# Remove tokens that start with #
data_tweet$text <- gsub("#\\S+", "", data_tweet$text)
```

Is there a more effective approach?

Answer (score 1):

For loops are generally speaking not used in R, and are quite slow with your current implementation. You can try using purrr::walk. Walk is used instead of map when you are not trying to return a unit of information, but are doing some task like reassigning a variable or writing a csv.

```
purrr::walk(all_words_vec, function(x) {data_tweet$text <- gsub(paste0("#\\<", x, "\\>"), paste(x, ""), data_tweet$text)})
    
data_tweet$text <- gsub("#\\S+", "", data_tweet$text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot to say that parallelizing will not help me, because the other cores are busy with the same code but different data frames.
I tried your code, but unfortunately it does not work for me. However it seems that the Purrr package is exactly what I’m looking for, so I will look more into that!

Comment: Ok, I have added a purrr only option. Please let me know if that solves your question. I cannot physically test it because the corpus doesn't download for some reason.

Comment: It's still not working. The error is:" Error in paste0("#\\<", ., "\\>") : object '.' not found". To download the corpus try install.packages("tm.corpus.Reuters21578", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at")

Comment: I still can't load the qdap package due to a Java error. Does making an anonymous function like above help?